# Sap Hana: function like "age" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, hana

Is there a function in SAP HANA which has the same semantics as `age` in PostgreSQL, that is, which returns the difference between a given time stamp and the current time stamp?

I know

```
ADD_YEARS(COLUMN_NAME, 2) <= NOW()
```

in SAP HANA would correspond to

```
(extract (year from age( COLUMN_NAME )) <= 2 )
```

in PostgreSQL. Unfortunately, this is not an option for me, since I don't have the information `<= 2`. What I am looking for is a way to translate `age(COLUMN_NAME)` (PostgreSQL) to SAP HANA.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SECONDS_BETWEEN(<timeA>, <timeB>)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy to get number of years by number of seconds (due to leap year, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

With SPS12 there is the `YEARS_BETWEEN()` function available:

```
  select years_between(current_date, add_years(current_date, -10)) from dummy;
```

> 10

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to calculate age in years in SPS11:

```
if(format(now(), 'MMDD') >= format("DateOfBirth", 'MMDD'),
    int(component(now(), 1)) - int(component("DateOfBirth", 1)),
        if(int(component(now(), 1)) = int(component("DateOfBirth", 1)), 0,
            int(component(now(), 1)) - int(component("DateOfBirth", 1)) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`select floor(days_between(to_date(timestamp1), to_date(timestamp2))/365) from dummy;`

it shall do the trick